# CSS solution for background image to cover full page with overflow elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I've got a page that uses an image as a background, which covers the full height and width of the page. Although I'm using Tailwind, the CSS for the image is basically:

```
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

That works fine. Until one of the elements on the page extends beyond my viewheight, which usually occurs when a toggle is switched on. CSS doesn't seem to recognize that the height of the page has changed, so it doesn't update the size of the image. It simply ends at the point where the bottom of the page used to be, before the extending element lengthened the page.

I've created a javascript solution for this that does some calculations based on the size of elements and directly sets the height of the image with inline styling, but it's not ideal, so I've been tasked with finding a pure CSS solution. I'm aware that updating the image height without adjusting the dimensions of the image will cause stretching, but in this case that's not a problem.

Obviously different from my webpage, but here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-ptolemy-k658o?file=/src/styles.css:14-165) demonstrating essentially the same problem.

Comment: Use the codesandbox as example, is it possible to let the toggle not to get outside the background to solve your problem? e.g. add style with overflow on toggle `{toggle && <div style={{maxHeight:"20vh", overflow:"auto"}}>{placeholder(20)}</div>}`

Comment: @VincentTang I was told not to allow scrolling on the expandable div when I initially made the page, but if another solution doesn't present itself I may end up doing this anyway, since it might be preferable to a javascript solution.

Comment: Once set to 100% this just covers the display size. And overflow content isn't really considered as display size. The best way to do this I'd assume is to use js but this might end up stretching your image in different display sizes. I'd advise using containers and each container to have its own background feel reflecting what content it covers, having a row-based approach for your page. Using 100% is if only you want your page to not be more than that this means you have to fit all your content in 100% height.